# What is REST call and how to send a REST call?

Tags: rest

I want to ask some questions about the REST call. I am the green for the REST call and I would like to like what is REST call and how to use the URL to send a REST call to the server. Can anyone give me some basic tutorial or link for my to reference?

Besides, if I want to send a REST call to the server, what should I do? Do I need to set something in the URL? or set something in the server? Thank you.

Comment: The StackOverflow "REST" tag has an about page that has useful links: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/info

Comment: This question has been asked many times before here.  Did you search for existing questions?

Comment: @DarrelMiller If it has been asked many times before, you ought to mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 18):

REST is just a software architecture style for exposing resources.

- Use HTTP methods explicitly.
- Be stateless.
- Expose directory structure-like URIs.
- Transfer XML, JavaScript Object Notation (JSON), or both.

A typical REST call to return information about customer 34456 could look like:

```
http://example.com/customer/34456
```

Have a look at the [IBM tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) for REST web services

Comment: REST is not limited to any particular media types.  Use test/plain, image/jpeg, text/html, application/xhtml, create your own.

Answer (score 11):

REST is somewhat of a revival of old-school HTTP, where the actual HTTP verbs (commands) have semantic meaning.  Til recently, apps that wanted to update stuff on the server would supply a form containing an 'action' variable and a bunch of data.  The HTTP command would almost always be `GET` or `POST`, and would be almost irrelevant.  (Though there's almost always been a proscription against using GET for operations that have side effects, in reality a lot of apps don't care about the command used.)

With REST, you might instead `PUT /profiles/cHao` and send an XML or JSON representation of the profile info.  (Or rather, I would -- you would have to update your own profile.  :)  That'd involve logging in, usually through HTTP's built-in authentication mechanisms.)  In the latter case, what you want to do is specified by the URL, and the request body is just the guts of the resource involved.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer has some details.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I still not completely understand. Do you mean that I have to set something in the .xml, or just add the para in the URL like GET.

Comment: @Questions: there usually aren't "params" the same way you'd use them in a GET request.  `PUT /profiles/cHao` says what to do, since a RESTful service would expose `/profiles/cHao` as a resource (ie: i might also `GET /profiles/cHao` and get back an XML or JSON version of my profile), and the `PUT` part says i want to replace it.  The only things that'd need setting are the request body (ie: the profile itself, which will usually be in XML or JSON) and either a username and password or a client certificate (since most services won't let strangers modify someone else's stuff).