# Unique row in DB

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have a table with huge data. I am storing logging details of [rest call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861527/what-is-rest-call-and-how-to-send-a-rest-call), where `sentTime` and a combination of three fields let say (COL1, COL2, COL3) are unique.

I need to get the last call for each rest call.

For example, if API1, API2, and API3 are called 10 times each, I have around 30 rows in my table. I need the last calls of all 3 API's so I will get 3 rows, one for each API.

I am using following query:

```
SELECT tb.id
FROM Table1 (nolock) tb 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(sentTime) as lastSentTime 
    FROM Table1 (nolock) GROUP BY col1, col2, col3) a 
        ON a.col1 = tb.col1 AND 
           a.col2 = tb.col2 AND 
           a.col2 = tb.col2 AND 
           a.lastSentTime = tb.sentTime
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

For example:

```
id  Name    Sent_Time      Temp_id  Temp_id2
1   Delete  04/03/16 17:54  AB      2222701
2   Update  04/03/16 17:54  UD      6900001
3   Create  04/03/16 17:54  EL      2017301
4   Read    04/03/16 17:54  AB      2670001
5   Update  08/03/16 17:54  UD      1069501
6   Create  08/03/16 17:54  EL      3490801
```

Except there are millions of rows.
The combination of name, Temp_id and Temp_id2 is unique.

In java I have taken all the data and put it into a HashMap with key as `name + Temp_id + Temp_id2`. So that it is unique. Is it possible I can get the same data through a query?

Comment: When you write *last call* do you mean the *most recent* call? How do you distinguish rows that come from different REST calls?

Comment: Please add some sample data and your expected result ;).

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: OllieJones : Name, Temp_id and Temp_id2 is unique.

shA.t : I have added
id  Name Sent_Time Temp_id Temp_id2
1 Delete 04/03/16 17:54 AB 2222701
2 Update 04/03/16 17:54 UD 6900001
3 Create 04/03/16 17:54 EL 2017301
4 Read 04/03/16 17:54 AB 2670001
5 Update 08/03/16 17:54 UD 1069501
6 Create 08/03/16 17:54 EL 3490801

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. I guess each distinct REST call has its own values of `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` and you want the most recent.

```
SELECT MAX(sentTime) mostrecent_sentTime,
       col1, col2, col3
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  Its not working.
we can say combination of col1, col2, col3 unique.

Comment: I was taking all the data and using hash map as Key col1, col2, col3.
I got all the latest data related to each api (col1 , col2 , col3). 

Is it possible same I can do using query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the columns in the row, then use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by sentTime desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If your table has only four columns (or you only care about four columns), then aggregation as suggested by @OllieJones is perhaps more reasonable.